# Page number for dynamically generated pages in mPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf, codeigniter-3

I am using mPDF with Codeigniter for creating PDF files. I have a problem when adding page number.
I have some result sets that are generated via database queries and I pass them to my html file to display that data. According to the number of results it creates and converts to pdf format with number of pages. Problem is I cannot add page numbers when it generates more than one page.
I am using the basic examples for this operation.
Please help me on this!

My controller code

```
$result_1 = $this->Vessel_model->getManifestVesselDetails($vesselId,$containerId);
$result_2 = $this->Vessel_model->getVesselDetailsByContainer($vesselId,$containerId);
$result_3 = $this->Vessel_model->getDDByVesselContainer($vesselId,$containerId);

$data['agentDetails'] = $this->Vessel_model->getShippingAgents();        
$data['DD_SDNumber'] = $this->DD_SDNumber;
$data['DDdetails'] = $result_3;
$data['containerDetails'] = $result_2;
$data['vesselcontainerDetails'] = $result_1;

$html = $this->load->view('reports/tri_shipping_manifest_PDF', $data, true);
//this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
$pdfFilePath = APPPATH.'/'.date('Y-m-d').$result_1->vessel.'-'.$result_1->serialno.".pdf";
$pdfFilePath3 = date('Y-m-d').$result_1->vessel.'-'.$result_1->serialno.".pdf";

$this->load->library('pdfreports');
$this->pdf = $this->pdfreports->load();
//$this->pdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');
$this->pdf->AddPage('L','',1,'i','on'); 
$this->pdf->WriteHTML($html,0);
$this->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath3, "D");
$this->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "F");
```

Comment: show us your code for generating multiplage pdf

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: can you please also add link to that basic example?

Comment: what do u mean by link??

Comment: In last sentence you wrote i'm using the basic exaples for this operation. There are many examples about mPDF. Share the link of your this example

Comment: please ignore that.i am following the mPDF manual.that's what i want you to know.

Comment: can any body tell me how  to do this?? or any alternatives.??

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how current code should look like, because i don't know much about mPDF, but i would suggest you to use domPdf with Codeigniter, because is much simpler then this library.
You can find [domPdf here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/PDF-generation-using-dompdf)

Since we don't know what is the output for those variables and what should be printed in pdf, i can only suggest some generally code created with domPdf

create helper:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    function pdf_create($html, $filename='', $stream=TRUE){
      require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");         
      $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
      $dompdf->load_html($html);
      $dompdf->render();
      $dompdf->set_paper("A4");
      if ($stream) {
        $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf",1);
      } else {
        return $dompdf->output();
      }
    }
?>
```

create controller for pdf

```
<?php
  $data['store']=$res;  
  $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
  $html = $this->load->view('store/sales_pdf', $data, true);
  $html.= $this->load->view('footer');
  $filename="salesbill".$id;
  pdf_create($html, $filename);
  $data = pdf_create($html, '', false);
  write_file('name', $data); 
?>
```

And your pdf HTML would look something like this

```
<html>
  <head>
   <style>
     @page { margin: 180px 50px; }
     #header { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: -180px; right: 0px; height: 150px; background-color: orange; text-align: center; }
     #footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: -180px; right: 0px; height: 150px; background-color: lightblue; }
     #footer .page:after { content: counter(page, upper-roman); }
   </style>
  <body>
   <div id="header">
     <h1>Widgets Express</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
     <p class="page">Page <?php $PAGE_NUM ?></p>
   </div>
   <div id="content">
     <p>the first page</p>
     <p style="page-break-before: always;">the second page</p>
   </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This answer is based on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776668/adding-header-and-footer-with-page-number-in-dompdf)
Also here is nice domPdf [debug helper page](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php)
I hope this answer helps you out